# How to make a link from one HTML document to another HTML document and also includes a quick link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to link from one page to the other. But it should also be scrolled down after I came to the other document. I don't know if you can do that with this code...
I know that you can use it to link to other sites and also make quick links, but is that also possible at the same time?
also looked at some other posts, but they are too complex for my brain. xD

LG JJ

`<a name="anker" href="#anker"></a>`

Comment: If the page is on the same site: `<a  href="YourOtherPage.html#anker">Link to your other page</a>`.  If the page is on another site:  `<a  href="https://www.SomeOtherSite.com/YourOtherPage.html#anker">Link to some other page on a different site</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can link to an item from another file using **/file#id** adress. Take a look at this example.

Inside **file1.html**:

```
<h1>This is file 1</h1>
<a href="file2.html#item">Link</a>
```

Inside **file2.html**:

```
<h1>This is file 2</h1>
<div>
    Something
</div>
<p id="item">Hello</p>
```

for smooth scrolling effect use

```
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

and link this to **file2.html**.

Comment: Ty for your help. I kept the code name="anker"... I just deleted it and now it works fine :)